# Pandas sum column of one table based on pairs of dates from another table table date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
`df1`:

```
    date        poly_name
0   2018-01-29  zamg_4905_poly4
1   2018-03-25  zamg_4905_poly4
2   2018-03-30  zamg_4905_poly4
3   2018-04-04  zamg_4905_poly4
4   2018-04-11  zamg_4905_poly4
5   2018-04-19  zamg_4905_poly4
6   2018-04-21  zamg_4905_poly4
7   2018-04-29  zamg_4905_poly4
8   2018-05-06  zamg_4905_poly4
9   2018-05-19  zamg_4905_poly4

df2

    date        rain (mm)
0   2018-03-22  0.3
1   2018-03-23  0.3
2   2018-03-24  0.0
3   2018-03-25  0.0
4   2018-03-26  0.3
5   2018-03-27  2.0
6   2018-03-28  17.6
7   2018-03-29  1.5
8   2018-03-30  0.0
9   2018-03-31  4.0
10  2018-04-01  4.8
11  2018-04-02  0.0
12  2018-04-03  0.0
13  2018-04-04  0.0
14  2018-04-05  2.1
15  2018-04-06  0.0
16  2018-04-07  0.0
17  2018-04-08  0.0
18  2018-04-09  0.0
19  2018-04-10  0.0
```

I would like to sum the `rain (mm)` (from `df2`) for every pair of consecutive dates from `df1`, and to add that sum to the row of the latest date of the two.

For example: the first pair of consecutive dates from `df1` is `2018-01-29` and `2018-03-25`, the sum of the `rain (mm)` for this pair is `0.3+0.3+0.0+0.0 = 0.6`. And I would like to add this value (0.6) to a new column in `df1` in row #1 (the row where `date=2018-03-25`). The second pair of dates will be `2018-03-25` and `2018-03-30`, here the sum of the rain will be: `0.0+0.3+2.0+17.6+1.5+0.0 = 21.4`, and that value should be added at row #2 in `df1`.

To achieve that I can create a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a different pair of dates, then write a function that will iterate that list of tuples and slice `df2` according to the i-th tuple and then sum the sliced `df2`.

I wonder if there is a more pythonic/elegant/efficient way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to get all the dates from df2 between two dates of df1. First convert to datetime columns and `sort_values` per date if not in your data.

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

# df1 = df1.sort_values('date')
# df2 = df2.sort_values('date')
```

Now perform the merge_asof and keep the dates from df1 in another column that will be use to group after:

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df2, df1[['date']].assign(date1 = df1['date']), on='date'))
#         date  rain (mm)      date1
# 0  2018-03-22        0.3 2018-01-29 # date from df2 are now align to previous date from df1
# 1  2018-03-23        0.3 2018-01-29
# 2  2018-03-24        0.0 2018-01-29
# 3  2018-03-25        0.0 2018-03-25 # only problem, the end date is not included, but easy fix
# 4  2018-03-26        0.3 2018-03-25
# 5  2018-03-27        2.0 2018-03-25
# 6  2018-03-28       17.6 2018-03-25
# 7  2018-03-29        1.5 2018-03-25
# 8  2018-03-30       10.0 2018-03-30 # same here, note that I changed the rain value to 10
# 9  2018-03-31        4.0 2018-03-30 # it will help to see the fix for end date value
```

So now that the main method is explain, you can `groupby` date1 after the `merge_asof` and `sum`.

```
res = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1[['date']].assign(date1 = df1['date']), on='date')\
        .groupby('date1').sum()
print(res)
#             rain (mm)
# date1                
# 2018-01-29        0.6
# 2018-03-25       21.4
# 2018-03-30       18.8
# 2018-04-04        2.1
```

You can add the value of rain from the end date reindexing df2 and shift the value backward.

```
res = res.add(df2.set_index('date')['rain (mm)']
                 .reindex(res.index).shift(-1).fillna(0), # to get end date value align
              axis=0)
print(res)
#             rain (mm)
# date1                
# 2018-01-29        0.6
# 2018-03-25       31.4 # the rain of 10 at the date of 2018-03-30 was added to previous group
# 2018-03-30       18.8
# 2018-04-04        2.1
```

and finally, add the column back to df1 using `map`

```
df1['total_rain'] = df1['date'].map(res['rain (mm)'])
print(df1)
#         date        poly_name  total_rain
# 0 2018-01-29  zamg_4905_poly4         0.6
# 1 2018-03-25  zamg_4905_poly4        31.4
# 2 2018-03-30  zamg_4905_poly4        18.8
# 3 2018-04-04  zamg_4905_poly4         2.1
# 4 2018-04-11  zamg_4905_poly4         NaN # not enough data from df2, but shold work as well
# 5 2018-04-19  zamg_4905_poly4         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems like too many lines of code to me. Also, in the final `dataframe` you show, the `total_rain` should be shifted - the value `0.6` should be row #1. What I eventually did was to iterate over the dates from `df1` and slice `df2` accordingly, and sum the total rain, all in one list comprehension.  
`df1_dates = df1['date'].tolist()` ;
`df1['rain_sum'] = [0]+[df2[df2['date'].between(df1_dates[i],df1_dates[i+1])]['rain (mm)'].sum() for i in range(len(df1_dates)-1)]`